# counting in sql in subquery in the table

Tags: oracle10g

```
 DNO DNAME

 ----- -----------
 1 Research
 2 Finance

 EN   ENAME      CITY           SALARY        DNO JOIN_DATE
  --  ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
 E1   Ashim      Kolkata         10000          1 01-JUN-02
 E2   Kamal      Mumbai          18000          2 02-JAN-02
 E3   Tamal      Chennai          7000          1 07-FEB-04
 E4   Asha       Kolkata          8000          2 01-MAR-07
 E5   Timir      Delhi            7000          1 11-JUN-05
```

//find all departments that have more than 3 employees.

My try

```
select deptt.dname 
from deptt,empl 
where deptt.dno=empl.dno and (select count(empl.dno) from empl group by empl.dno)>3;
```

Comment: Homework question are kinda frowned here,try something or write some pseudo code you think it will work.

Comment: select deptt.dname from deptt,empl where deptt.dno=empl.dno and (select count(empl.dno) from empl group by empl.dno)>3;

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
*
from departments d
inner join (
           select dno from employees group by dno having count(*) > 3
           ) e on d.dno = e.dno
```

There are many approaches to this problem but almost all will use `GROUP BY` and the `HAVING` clause. That clause allows you to filter results of aggregate functions. Here it is used to choose only those records where the count is greater than 3.

In the query structure used above the group by is handled on the employee table only, then the result (which is known as a `derived table`) is joined by an `INNER JOIN` to the departments table. This inner join only allows matching records so this has the effect of filtering the departments table to only those which have a count() of greater than 3.

An advantage of this query structure is fewer records are joined, and also that all columns of the departments table are available for reporting. Disadvantage of this structure is the the count() of employees per department isn't visible.

Comment: IF you give the answer at least add some explanation.

Comment: it was in preparation

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

```
select deptt.dname 
 from deptt,empl 
where deptt.dno=empl.dno 
group by deptt.dname having count(1)>3;
```

Comment: @Mihai IF you think that it need an explanation just ask!

Comment: Obviously its for the OP so he will leave a little bit more knowledgeable rather than copy-paste.

Comment: @dursunsir you query is working fine.But can you tell me how does count(1) works.

Comment: it counts the existance, you don't have to count(1) you can use count(0) or count(11) or even count(*) as well